# Many instances of the same Actor evenly created across separate remote nodes?

Tags: mapreduce, akka

For scalability I would like the Map actor instance (named `mapActor` below) to be distributed across several remote nodes say `host1`, `host2` and `host3`. I'm not sure how can this be done in Akka  `application.conf` e.g.

```
MapReduceSystem {
  include "common"
  akka {
    actor {
      deployment {
        /mapActor {
          router = round-robin
          nr-of-instances = 48
          remote = "akka.tcp://MapReduceSystem@host1:2552,akka.tcp://MapReduceSystem@host2:2552,akka.tcp://MapReduceSystem@host3:2552" 
        }
        /reduceActor {
          remote = "akka.tcp://MapReduceSystem@host1:2552"
          router = round-robin
          nr-of-instances = 1
        }
        /masterActor {
          remote = "akka.tcp://MapReduceSystem@host1:2552"
          nr-of-instances = 1
        }
      }
    }
    remote.enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    remote.netty.tcp.hostname = "host1"
  }
}
```

For completness here is my `common.conf`:

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote.netty.tcp.port = 0
  remote.log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
}
```

Note the definition of `mapActor` I'd like to provide 3 hosts to create instances of this Actor, 16 in each but the `remote` parameter takes only one host. How can I do this?

To my understanding this configuration would correspond to the system startup machine `host1`, how would the configuration look on the `host2` and `host3`?

Comment: The deployment configuration is only needed on that host where you call `actorOf`, the target nodes will be told what to do.

Comment: Perfect! this is one bit of important information I was missing.

Comment: How is the code like in the target nodes? the main would not do any `actorOf` there then or?

Comment: If you can elaborate a complete answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/remoting.html#Routers_with_Remote_Destinations)

```
akka {
  actor {
    deployment {
     /serviceA/aggregation {
       router = "round-robin"
       nr-of-instances = 10
       target {
         nodes = ["akka.tcp://app@10.0.0.2:2552", "akka.tcp://app@10.0.0.3:2552"]
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So instead of `remote = "a,b,c"` you need `target.nodes = ["a","b","c"]`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the configuration syntax issue pointed out by pushy you don’t need to do anything beyond starting the systems at `host1` and `host2` before `host1` so that when the `/user/mapActor` is started its routees can successfully deployed onto them. The configuration is taken from `host1` and transported over to the other hosts, no further configuration is necessary, and no call to `actorOf` needs to be done on the worker hosts (at least not for the routers under discussion).